# 2018 Nissan Altima Brake problem when brakes are hot

Tags: brake-rotor

I drive a 2018 Nissan Altima. Lately I’ve heard a low rumbling sound sometimes sounds like grinding when the brakes are hot. I changed the brake pads and rotors and the problem continues. This only happen when braking slowly and when the brakes are pretty hot from stop and go traffic.

Comment: Have you considered the wherl bearings?

Comment: I haven’t however I dont think it’s the wheel bearings also the person who did my struts recently said they were good. Also I read the symptoms of bad wheel bearings and none matched the issues with mine when braking on hot brakes.